# How can I create a Kotlin project that builds with Gradle?

Tags: intellij-idea, gradle, kotlin

I'm trying to create a new Kotlin project that builds with Gradle using IntelliJ IDEA (2016.2.5 on Ubuntu 16.04). When I do this I immediately get an error message.

Here's what I'm trying:

1. Select "Create New Project" from Welcome Screen.
2. Select "Gradle" from left hand pane, "Kotlin (Java)" from right. Click "Next".
3. Enter "hello-world" as ArtifactId. Click Next.
4. Ensure "Create separate module from source set" and "Use default Gradle wrapper" are
   selected, nothing else is. Click "Next".
5. Use defaults for project name and location. Click "Finish".

I then immediately get this error:

```
Gradle 'hello-world' project refresh failed

Error: Could not find org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:1.1-M02-12.
       Searched in the following locations:
           https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/jetbrains/kotlin/kotlin-gradle-plugin/1.1-M02-12/kotlin-gradle-plugin-1.1-M02-12.pom
           https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/jetbrains/kotlin/kotlin-gradle-plugin/1.1-M02-12/kotlin-gradle-plugin-1.1-M02-12.jar
       Required by:
           :hello-world:unspecified
```

The generated `build.gradle` looks like this:

```groovy
version '1.0-SNAPSHOT'

buildscript {
    ext.kotlin_version = '1.1-M02-12'

    repositories {
        mavenCentral()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:$kotlin_version"
    }
}

apply plugin: 'kotlin'

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}

dependencies {
    compile "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib:$kotlin_version"
}
```

How can I create a Kotlin project that builds with Gradle correctly?

Comment: I followed your instructions on Intellij IDEA (2018.3 version) for how to create a Gradle project with Kotlin support, and at least nowawdays is working without any problems. Even with dependencies. Perhaps they have improved it substancially.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In your `build.gradle`, change `ext.kotlin_version` to be:

```
 ext.kotlin_version = '1.1-M02'
```

<sup>It's a minor bug that the IDE plugin puts its own version into build scripts, not the Kotlin version.</sup>

And also add the 1.1 EAP repository to the `repositories` in both `buildscript` and the root scope:

```
repositories {
    // ...
    maven { url "http://dl.bintray.com/kotlin/kotlin-eap-1.1" }
}
```

<sup>Kotlin artifacts related to EAP versions are not put into Maven Central like those of public releases, and this repository is not added automatically into the generated build script.</sup>

Then refresh the Gradle project, and the build should pass.

Feel free to check with [this `build.gradle` file](https://gist.github.com/h0tk3y/0112caf770d2d47bf9cf590c79ba225f).

Comment: Updated the answer since it was missing the EAP repository + added a link to an example.

Comment: Thanks! That seems to have fixed it. Though I don't really agree that a bug that makes the output broken in the base case is minor...

Comment: I'm getting an error "Unindexed remote maven repositories" referring to the  http://dl.bintray.com/kotlin/kotlin-eap-1.1 URL. If I open the repositories list that URL is highlighted in red, and says "Error" in the "Updated" column.

Comment: "Unindexed remote maven repositories" isn't actually an error, is it? As far as I understand, IDEA simply suggests indexing it, that will enable auto-completion and auto-import of the artifacts in that repository.

Comment: I get exactly the same error, @LaurenceGonsalves, did you solve it? If I leave the mouse on it, it says "Resource nexus-maven-repository-index.properties does not exist"

Comment: @elect which error are you referring to? The "Unindexed remote maven repositories" error, or the "Could not find org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin..." error?

Comment: @LaurenceGonsalves The first one

Comment: @elect No, I never solved that issue. If you figure it out I'd love to hear about how.